# Does this regex allow white spaces?

Tags: java, regex

What the following regex mean in java context?

```
[a-zA-Z\\s][a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+$
```

It should allow white spaces (`\t\n`...)? but seems only non-space strings pass.

Thanks

Comment: is that "\\s" or "\s" in the source file?

Comment: @jtahlborn It should be `\\s`. In Java, backslashes needs to be escaped.

Comment: http://regex101.com has a nice regex explainer :)

Answer (score 6):

This regular expression matches any ASCII letter or space followed by one or more ASCII alphanumeric or space characters at the end of a string. Both parts should match the `\r` and `\n` characters.

Comment: Correction: *English* letter. `Ö` is a letter too and will not be matched by either part of the regex. For example. Still, +1 from me for a succint answer that explains how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I'm assuming this is contained within quotes in the java source and hence why you have the double escape.

`[a-zA-Z\\s]` will match 1 uppercase/lowercase character (range a to z) or a space

`[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+` will match a uppercase/lowercase character (range a to z), a number or space one or more times \n

`$` is the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
(letter|<space>)alphanumericOrSpace<end>
```